# Access DynamonDB of Amazon Web Service from Android SDK

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

How to access DynamonDB of Amazon Web Service from Android SDK without through Token Vending Machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options, including one that was introduced by AWS very recently.

One option is to use [Web identity Federation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WIF.html).  Here, you put code in your app to have users log in with an identity provider like Login with Amazon, Google, or Facebook login, and as a result, your application gets temporary AWS credentials, when can be restricted to particular items or attributes in your DynamoDB tables using [Fine-grained access control](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/FGAC_DDB.html).

The new option is a service called [Amazon Cognito](http://aws.amazon.com/cognito/), which is a simple user identity and data synchronization service geared toward mobile apps.  I encourage you to take a look at this service and watch the short intro video to see if it suits your needs.  Even if you don't use the data synchronization component, you can still use the user identity management component, and have the same fine-grained access control capabilities as the other solution, but with additional login and user management capabilities like unauthenticated guest access.

Comment: Thank you. I had used Amazon Cognito to access AWS. It very pretty